# Multiple sites under one Django instance - Sites serve wrong content sometimes

Tags: django, apache, virtualhost

I have strange problem my django configuration. I have three similar sites running under one django project directory. I separated them with apache virtualhost. It's running great in most of cases, but somehow sometimes is under one domain content of another domain.

For instance domain.cz pretends as www.microsite.cz. So there is same content under two domains. Or domain.sk pretends as domain.cz. It happens randomly and it's hard to debug it. Usually I can see it from Google webmaster tools. When apache is restarted everything is ok.

Has anyone idea what can cause this strange behaviour?

This is my configuration httpd.conf:

```
ServerRoot "/home/me/webapps/domain/apache2"

LoadModule dir_module        modules/mod_dir.so
LoadModule env_module        modules/mod_env.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
LoadModule mime_module       modules/mod_mime.so
LoadModule rewrite_module    modules/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule setenvif_module   modules/mod_setenvif.so
LoadModule wsgi_module       modules/mod_wsgi.so

LogFormat "%{X-Forwarded-For}i %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
KeepAlive Off
Listen 53696
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-SSL on HTTPS=1


MaxSpareThreads 10
MinSpareThreads 2
ServerLimit 3
ThreadsPerChild 10

WSGIPythonPath /home/me/webapps/domain:/home/me/webapps/domain/lib/python2.6/site-packages


NameVirtualHost *
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName domain.cz
    ServerAlias www.domain.cz

    CustomLog /home/me/logs/user/domain/access_com.log combined
    ErrorLog /home/me/logs/user/domain/error_com.log

    WSGIDaemonProcess domain_cz processes=3 python-path=/home/me/webapps/domain:/home/me/webapps/domain/lib/python2.6 threads=2
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/me/webapps/domain/apache2/conf/cz.wsgi

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain\.cz$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://domain1.cz/$1 [R=301]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName domain.sk
    ServerAlias www.domain.sk

    CustomLog /home/me/logs/user/domain/access_sk.log combined
    ErrorLog /home/me/logs/user/domain/error_sk.log

    WSGIDaemonProcess domain_sk python-path=/home/me/webapps/domain:/home/me/webapps/domain/lib/python2.6 threads=3
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/me/webapps/domain/apache2/conf/sk.wsgi

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} slavne-domain\.sk$ [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} slavnedomain\.sk$ [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.in$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://domain.in/$1 [R=301]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName www.microsite.cz
    ServerAlias microsite.cz

    CustomLog /home/me/logs/user/domain/access_cz_laska.log combined
    ErrorLog /home/me/logs/user/domain/error_cz_laska.log

    WSGIDaemonProcess domain_cz_micro python-path=/home/me/webapps/domain:/home/me/webapps/domain/lib/python2.6 threads=3
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/me/webapps/domain/apache2/conf/cz_micro.wsgi

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain-o-lasce\.net$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://www.domain-o-lasce.net/$1 [R=301]
</VirtualHost>
```

This is example of my wsgi script:

```
import os
import sys

from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'domain.settings.cz'
# or domain.settings.sk or domain.settings.cz_micro 

application = WSGIHandler()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing WSGIProcessGroup directive. Go read:

- http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/CheckingYourInstallation#Embedded_Or_Daemon_Mode
- http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2012/10/why-are-you-using-embedded-mode-of.html
- http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2012/10/requests-running-in-wrong-django.html

Your separate applications are not running in separate processes as you think they would be.